# Why can I not use an exclamation mark in bash' echo, not even when it is escaped?

Tags: bash

My question is simple:

```
$ echo "Hello!"
sh: !": event not found
```

What is `!` in this case? I then tried `echo "Match\!"`, but that resolves to `Match\!`. How do I have to write the statement?

Comment: `bash` imported a feature from C shell that should have stayed in the C shell - and the sea shell should have stayed on the sea shore, far from the nearest computer.

Comment: See the `QUOTING` section of the `bash` man page. It describes the effects of single- and double-quotes on shell metacharacters, including `!` when history expansion is enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use single quotes:

```
echo 'Hello!'
Hello!
```

Otherwise in double quotes shell attempts to expand `!` to an event from the history..

Comment: Now you were faster :)

Comment: @fedorqui: One of those rare occasions :)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the effect of single and double quotes on expansion.

Comment: @Tobias: It is really important to know single quote and double quote difference in shell programming. Because unix shells don't expand variables in single quote.

Comment: Yes, I see! `echo $foo` is `echo "$foo"`, but it does not equal `echo '$foo'`. The last one prints the string `$foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off history expansion with `set +H` and re-enable it with `set -H`